# SQL And NULL Values in where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, null

So I have a simple query that returns a listing of products

```
SELECT     Model, CategoryID
FROM         Products
WHERE     (Model = '010-00749-01')
```

This returns

```
010-00749-01    00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
010-00749-01    NULL
```

Which is correct, so I wanted only the products whose CategoryID is not '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000' so I have

```
SELECT     Model, CategoryID
FROM         Products
WHERE     (Model = '010-00749-01') 
AND (CategoryID <> '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000')
```

But this returns no result. So I changed the query to

```
SELECT     Model, CategoryID
FROM         Products
WHERE     (Model = '010-00749-01') 
AND ((CategoryID <> '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000') OR  (CategoryID  IS NULL))
```

Which returns expected result

```
010-00749-01    NULL
```

Can someone explain this behavior to me?
MS SQL Server 2008

Comment: the wiki article is quite good at explaining NULL - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_%28SQL%29

Comment: @Russ Cam - you should've posted this as an answer...

Comment: I felt it was more of a lmgtfy answer :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check out the full reference on [Books Online](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188048(v=SQL.100).aspx) - by default ANSI_NULLS is on meaning you'd need to use the approach you have done. Otherwise, you could switch that setting OFF at the start of the query to switch the behaviour round.

> When SET ANSI_NULLS is ON, a SELECT
>   statement that uses WHERE column_name
>   = NULL returns zero rows even if there are null values in column_name. A
>   SELECT statement that uses WHERE
>   column_name <> NULL returns zero rows
>   even if there are nonnull values in
>   column_name. 
>   
> ...
>  
>   When SET ANSI_NULLS
>   is ON, all comparisons against a null
>   value evaluate to UNKNOWN. When SET
>   ANSI_NULLS is OFF, comparisons of all
>   data against a null value evaluate to
>   TRUE if the data value is NULL.

Here's a simple example to demonstrate the behaviour with regard to comparisons against NULL:

```
-- This will print TRUE
SET ANSI_NULLS OFF;
IF NULL <> 'A'
    PRINT 'TRUE'
ELSE
    PRINT 'FALSE'

-- This will print FALSE
SET ANSI_NULLS ON;
IF NULL <> 'A'
    PRINT 'TRUE'
ELSE
    PRINT 'FALSE'
```

Comment: Be careful, setting ANSI_NULLS to `off` will decrease performance and increase logical reads.  Turning it on affects the query plan.

Comment: @Vol7ron Really merited a downvote?! That v harsh for what is a correct answer. If you honestly feel it  warrants a downvote, fair enough but imho seems odd and not an honest vote

Comment: What merited a downvote?  I don't think it merits a down or an up.  It's an answer.  I wouldn't go so far to say it's "correct" either.  Implementing this will take a performance hit, but more importantly it is technically not SQL standard, the moment you implement that, you are straying from ISO.  One of the best things about SQL is the ability to go from platform to platform, you're giving that up here.  `Coalesce` is a better solution.  As I've stated, if you're worried about the performance impact then index that field w/ the function, otherwise clean up the underlying data.

Comment: warning: ANSI_NULLS should be avoided, MS says no, and its Deprecation is at hand: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188048.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Basically, a NULL is the *absence of any value*. So trying to compare the NULL in CategoryId to a varchar value in the query will always result in a false evaluation.

You might want to try using the COALESCE function, something like:

```
SELECT     ModelId, CategoryID 
FROM       Products 
WHERE      (ModelId = '010-00749-01')  
AND        ( COALESCE( CategoryID, '' ) <> '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000' )
```

**EDIT**

As noted by `AdaTheDev` the COALESCE function will negate any indices that may exist on the CategoryID column, which can affect the query plan and performance.

Comment: Be careful with this approach, as the COALESCE could result in a less optimal execution plan by preventing an index seek on that column

Comment: Ada is correct, the COALESCE does have an effect on the execution plan. Will edit my answer to include.

Answer (score 2):

In general, you have to remember that NULL generally means UNKNOWN. That means if you say `CategoryID <> '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'` you have to assume that the query will only return values that it KNOWS will meet your criteria. Since there is a NULL (UNKNOWN) result, it does not actually know if that record meets your criteria and therefore will not be returned in the dataset.

Comment: While the other answers contain more detail, I like this one because of the simplicity.  It's understandable even to a non-techie, and therefore valuable to newer developers.  +1.

Answer (score 1):

look at this:

```
1=1        --true
1=0        --false
null=null  --false
null=1     --false

1<>1       --false
1<>0       --true
null<>null --false
null<>1    --false    <<<--why you don't get the row with: AND (CategoryID <> '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000')
```

Comment: Technically SQL uses a three-valued logic system, so all of your comparisons with NULL yield UNKNOWN rather than FALSE. See: [SQL and the Snare of Three-Valued Logic](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/sql-and-the-snare-of-three-valued-logic/).

Comment: call it `false` or `unknown`, it doesn't really matter, because the row is not included in the result set, which is what the question was all about.

Answer (score 0):

Null gets special treatment. You need to explicitly test for null. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188795.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You may try using the `Coalesce` function to set a default value for fields that have `null`:

```
   SELECT    Model , CategoryID
   FROM      Products
   WHERE     Model = '010-00749-01'
     AND     Coalesce(CategoryID,'') <> '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'
```

I think the problem lies in your understanding of `NULL` which basically means "nothing."  You can't compare anything to nothing, much like you can't divide a number by 0.  It's just rules of math/science.

**Edit:**
As Ada has pointed out, this could cause an indexed field to no longer use an index.

Solution:

- You can create an index using the coalesce function: eg `create index ... coalesce(field)`
- You can add a `not null` constraint to prevent NULLs from ever appearing
- A de facto standard of mine is to always assign default values and never allow nulls

Comment: Be careful with this approach, as the COALESCE could result in a less optimal execution plan by preventing an index seek on that column

Comment: This could be true, however, you can create an index as `coalesce(field)`, or add a not null constraint to prevent NULLs from ever appearing.  A de facto standard of mine is to always assign default values and never allow nulls.