# SQL WHERE clause not returning rows when field has NULL value

Tags: c#, sql, datatable

Ok, so I'm aware of this issue:

> When SET ANSI_NULLS is ON, all comparisons against a null value evaluate to UNKNOWN

- [SQL And NULL Values in where clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3937562/sql-and-null-values-in-where-clause)
- [SQL Server return Rows that are not equal <> to a value and NULL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4453622/sql-server-return-rows-that-are-not-equal-to-a-value-and-null)

However, I am trying to query a `DataTable`.

I could add to my query:

```
OR col_1 IS NULL OR col_2 IS NULL
```

for every column, but my table has 47 columns, and I'm building dynamic SQL (string concatenation), and it just seems like a pain to do that.  Is there another solution?

**I was to bring back all the rows that have `NULL` values in the `WHERE` comparison.**

**UPDATE**

Example of query that gave me problems:

```
string query = col_1 not in ('Dorothy', 'Blanche') and col_2 not in ('Zborna', 'Devereaux')
grid.DataContext = dataTable.Select(query).CopyToDataTable();
```

(didn't retrieve rows if/when `col_1 = null` and/or `col_2 = null`)

Comment: Please show an example of the kind of query that causes you problems.

Comment: if your columns are all strings, a really dirty way to do it would be to make a column that's a concatenation of all the columns you're querying and then check if that's null :)

Comment: If you have to perform an identical test on many columns of identical types, my guess is that such values should be put in a separate table with a foreign key to the first table. But there is no way to know for sure until you post your table schemas.

Comment: FYI: I'm not querying an actual DBMS!!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So you mean something like (example with 2 columns)

```
WHERE (col1 = 'abc' or col1 is null)
  AND (col2 = 3 or col2 is null)
```

But you want to include the nulls always?
This should work

```
WHERE isnull(col1,'abc') = 'abc'
  AND isnull(col2, 3) = 3
```

Comment: I just when with your first example, but without the `WHERE/AND`.  Example: `(col_1 not in ('Sophia', 'Rose') or col_1 is null) and (col_2 not in ('Petrillo', 'Nylund') or col_2 is null)`

Answer (score 4):

Are you doing this because you want to get the NULL values, or because you don't want the NULL values to interfere with your comparisons?

For example, this:

```
WHERE col_1 != 'John'
```

will not return any rows for which col_1 is NULL (you've indicated in your question that you know this).

If you're trying to get the `col_1 IS NULL` rows to return with a WHERE clause like the above, you have two options in MS SQL (one in mySql).

In both MS SQL and mySql, the `coalesce()` function will allow you to do a comparison of this sort.  In MS SQL (I believe this is the same for mySql, too), its function is to take two or more arguments, and evaluate them in order, returning the first non-NULL one it finds.  In MS SQL, there's a shorthand function called `isNull()`, which is like `coalesce()` but only takes two parameters.

In the above example, you would do the following:

```
WHERE coalesce(col_1,'') != 'John'
```

and that would return rows that have col_1 IS NULL as well as rows that have non-NULL values in col_1 which do not equate to 'John'.

If this is your real goal, then this technique should work for you.

Comment: +1: Your suggestion is great for dealing with this situation, if I was using a DBMS, but this question was about `DataTable.Select()` in C#.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know C#, and was responding based on the sql tag on your post.  Hopefully some C# expert can help you out better than I did!