# SQL Server where column in where clause is null

Tags: sql, sql-server, null, where-clause

Let's say that we have a table named `Data` with `Id` and `Weather` columns. Other columns in that table are not important to this problem. The `Weather` column can be null.

I want to display all rows where `Weather` fits a condition, but if there is a null value in `weather` then display null value.

My SQL so far:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Data d
WHERE (d.Weather LIKE '%'+COALESCE(NULLIF('',''),'sunny')+'%' OR d.Weather IS NULL)
```

My results are wrong, because that statement also shows values where `Weather` is null if condition is not correct (let's say that users mistyped wrong).

I found similar topic, but there I do not find appropriate answer. 
[SQL WHERE clause not returning rows when field has NULL value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4697507/sql-where-clause-not-returning-rows-when-field-has-null-value)

Please help me out.

Comment: The query will return rows where Weather is like what the user typed in, or where Weather is null. Are you saying that is the user types in something apart from 'sunny' you want to return nothing, not even the null values?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: I didn't understand your requirement!!!

Comment: In that case you need to have a list of valid Weather values and validate against that in the database, or else validate in the client that calls the database - before it calls the database - that they have typed in a valid Weather value.

Comment: Seems to complicated (I have a large database), will try if I do not find fine sultion. Thanks.

Comment: Why not just use ISNULL? "WHERE ISNULL(d.Weather,'sunny') LIKE '%sunny%'". Granted, you need to pass the parameter twice, but that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: @Kahn I still get null results If I do that. Do you think "WHERE ISNULL(d.Weather,'') LIKE '%sunny%'?

Comment: @michael24B: Ah, sorry I misunderstood the problem. As others have assumed, you're likely using a parameter to pass for weather? Let's say the name of the param is #WPARAM, in that case your WHERE clause could look like this: "WHERE ISNULL(Weather,'#WPAR') LIKE '%'+ISNULL(#WPARAM,'#WPAR')+'%'" That way NULLs will match, or you can just do "WHERE (Weather LIKE '%'+#WPARAM+'%' OR (Weather IS NULL AND #WPARAM IS NULL))". You need to check the execution plan to determine which is more efficient though, I don't have time to set up the sample data. :) Used # in place of (AT) to avoid notifications.

Comment: Thanks, will try also that, but so far it works with that: WHERE ISNULL(d.Weather,'') LIKE '%parameter%'. Funny thing, huh? :)
With that, If parameter is null then I get all values (also null, which is good), If the parameter is not null than I also get correct result.

Comment: Hmm, apparently what @simonatrcl was sayin is that you're trying to validate the parameter against existing values and return matching rows if found, or if both the parameter and the weather column in the table are null. In that case dasblinkenlight's solution below is probably among your best bets. There really are a lot of ways to interpret your question here. :) EDIT TO COMMENT ABOVE: That means your parameter is passed as '', not null. Which means if there are rows where weather is '' instead of NULL, they are interpreted the same way.

Comment: Thanks for good explanation. I'll have that in mind if something goes wrong in the future..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your query is correct for the general task of treating `NULL`s as a match. If you wish to suppress `NULL`s when there are no other results, you can add an `AND EXISTS ...` condition to your query, like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Data d
WHERE d.Weather LIKE '%'+COALESCE(NULLIF('',''),'sunny')+'%'
   OR (d.Weather IS NULL AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Data dd WHERE dd.Weather LIKE '%'+COALESCE(NULLIF('',''),'sunny')+'%'))
```

The additional condition ensures that `NULL`s are treated as matches only if other matching records exist.

You can also use a [common table expression](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) to avoid duplicating the query, like this:

```
WITH cte (id, weather) AS
(
    SELECT * 
    FROM Data d
    WHERE d.Weather LIKE '%'+COALESCE(NULLIF('',''),'sunny')+'%'
)
SELECT * FROM cte
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM Data WHERE weather is NULL AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM cte)
```

> statement show also values where Wether is null if condition is not correct (let say that users typed wrong sunny).

This suggests that the constant `'sunny'` is coming from end-user's input. If that is the case, you need to parameterize your query to avoid [SQL injection attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).